# Accessing Data from JSON Feed with Multiple Keys

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON feed that has two keys or categories. Not sure what to call them but they're "Results" and "PendedApps". What I'm trying to do is create two tables with all data from each of the two feeds. An example of the JSON feed is below.

```
{ "Results": [ { "ClientFirst": "John", "ClientLast": "Doe", "ClientState": "CA", 
"Product": "Recliner", "RecDate": "4/1/2015", "Status": "Sold" }, { "ClientFirst": "Jay", 
"ClientLast": "Doe", "ClientState": "CA", "Product": "Leather Loveseat", "RecDate": 
"3/28/2015", "Status": "Completed" } ] }{ "PendedApps": [ { "ClientFirst": "Joe",
 "ClientLast": "Schmidt", "ClientState": "CA", "Product": "Wicker Stool", 
"PendReason": "Credit card declined\r\n" } ] }
```

Here are a few things I've tried from other examples on this site:

I've tried accessing each key through a foreach loop. This returns the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

```
$content = json_decode($json);

foreach($content->Results->new as $entry){
    echo $entry->ClientFirst;
}
```

I've also tried dumping utf8_encoded data and returned *NULL*.

```
$content = json_decode($json);

$newjson = utf8_encode($json); 
$newerjson = preg_replace('/.+?({.+}).+/','$1',$newjson);
$data = json_decode($newerjson);

var_dump($data);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, here is the correction:

```
{
    "Results": [
        {
            "ClientFirst": "John",
            "ClientLast": "Doe",
            "ClientState": "CA",
            "Product": "Recliner",
            "RecDate": "4/1/2015",
            "Status": "Sold"
        },
        {
            "ClientFirst": "Jay",
            "ClientLast": "Doe",
            "ClientState": "CA",
            "Product": "Leather Loveseat",
            "RecDate": "3/28/2015",
            "Status": "Completed"
        }
    ],
    "PendedApps": [
        {
            "ClientFirst": "Joe",
            "ClientLast": "Schmidt",
            "ClientState": "CA",
            "Product": "Wicker Stool",
            "PendReason": "Credit card declined\r\n"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If it solves the problem, don't forget to mark the question as resolved.